# google is not defined in react app using create-react-app

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I create a react app using the cli called create-react-app. Look like Facebook did lots of things underneath, such as webpack etc. However, I guess it may also has some limitations. I try to follow [this tutorial](http://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/11/06/making-google-maps-work-with-react/) to load google map api. And when I debug my code, I can see the google map has been successfully referenced.[image].

But then I click play and let application finishes running. I got google is not defined error from webpackHotDevClient.js and my application crashes.

[image]

[image]

Since webpack compile the files on the fly, I assume it has trouble to load google map via https?

Any thoughts?

Comment: what does your `.eslintrc` look like?

Comment: Create React App doesn't support customising ESLint configuration so this comment is not very relevant in this case.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

As mentioned in the [user guide](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-global-variables), you need to explicitly read any global variables from `window`. Put this at the top of the file and it will work:

```
const google = window.google;
```

The reason we enforce this is because people commonly misunderstand the difference between local variables, imported modules, and global variables, and so we want to always make it clear in the code when you use a global variable.

By the way, this is not related to Webpack or HTTPS. You see this because we use a linting rule that forbids unknown global variables.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I had the same issue in Vue.js with Nuxt.js. Your answer worked for me as well.

Comment: thanks, i face the problem when use react-geosuggest and your answer help me.

Comment: I tried this but then I got an error saying to place imports at the top of the file. Putting this below the imports didn't work. So I had to use /* global google */ at the top.

Comment: Hi Dan, Just now i searched your "user guide" link for [window, global, explicit] and came up empty. Did the info on this move someplace else?

Comment: I had a weird issue where i could add a global script on my index page using `script src` and then calling the function (detectBrowser.js) without issue. Once it was deployed it wouldn't work unless i specified `window.detectBrowser()` There must be some difference between envs? It was deployed using npm ci, so it is possible dependencies were different.

Comment: When you need typescript:
type google = typeof window.google;

Answer (score 17):

I think the google variable is already available when you import google map from script in html. This error caused by Eslint, you can try and add the below line to the top of your file to disable ESlint

```
/*global google*/
```

Answer (score 7):

I have a better solution then @Dan's you can do it like this

```
window.google = window.google ? window.google : {}
```

OR

```
const google = window.google = window.google ? window.google : {}
```

If `google` is available then no problem if not then empty Object will be temporarily assigned till your scripts are loaded.

In case `es-lint` throws undefined google error, update [the globals in eslint configuration file](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/language-options#using-configuration-comments-1):

```
{
    "globals": {
        "google": "readonly"
    }
}
```

OR

For a specific file use case define like below on the top of the file

```
/*global google*/
```

Comment: yes, only this worked, because I was getting window.google as undefined and then run time error

Answer (score 5):

Hi you can use `withGoogleMap` like so:

```
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps";

const google = window.google;

class MapComponent extends Component {
....

<GoogleMap>
.....
.....
.....
</GoogleMap>

export default withGoogleMap(MapComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
    // ...
    "globals": {
     "google": "readonly"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add @types/googlemaps
```

OR

```
npm i --save @types/googlemaps
```

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React, you can use it like this eg.

```
function RenderGoogleButton (){
    function handleCallbackResponse(response) {
        console.log("CredencialJWT:  "+response.credential)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const google = window.google  //check this
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
            callback: handleCallbackResponse
        })

        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("signInDiv"),
            { theme: "outline", size: "large" }
        )
        console.log("RenderGoogleButton")
    }, [])        
    return (<div id="signInDiv"></div>)
}
```

Note: **const google = window.google** or **/* global google */** both are correct. On the above eg. I used the first one.