# 'Google' is not defined: adding Google Maps API in React JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps

React JS newbie here, so please bear with me.

I added the Google Maps API script in my `index.html` file, like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="root"></div>
  
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-IS-HERE"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then, I installed `google-maps-react` with `npm` so I could use it's components. I imported this library in my component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

class BaseMap extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            center: {lat: 42, lng: 14},
            zoom: 10
        }
    };

    render() {
        let location = {
            center: '',
            zoom: ''
        }

        return (
            <GoogleMapReact>
            </GoogleMapReact>
        );
    }

    myMethod(){
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    }
}

export default BaseMap;
```

However, when I try to use `google.maps.Geocoder`, I get:

```
Line 30:  'google' is not defined  no-undef
```

As I know, `google` should be a global, window object since I included the Google Maps API script in the html file. However, it isn't defined.

Any ideas? Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Okay, this seems to work:

The solution was to implicitly define `google` in a variable above the class, like this:

```
const google = window.google
```

Answered here:

[google is not defined in react app using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714895/google-is-not-defined-in-react-app-using-create-react-app)

Comment: In React Native, it's possible?

Comment: In React Native you need to use react-native-maps