# Error with React Component Using Google Maps API and @ubilabs/google-maps-react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm working on a React project that involves using the Google Maps API along with the @ubilabs/google-maps-react-hooks library. I've encountered an issue that I can't seem to resolve. Below is the code for my React component and the error I'm facing.

I'm attempting to create a component called GoogleMapsDirections that calculates and displays routes and estimated times of arrival (ETAs) for a list of students. I'm using the useDirectionsService and useGoogleMap hooks provided by @ubilabs/google-maps-react-hooks.

Code:

jsx
// GoogleMapsDirections.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useDirectionsService, useGoogleMap } from "@ubilabs/google-maps-react-hooks";

function GoogleMapsDirections({ students }) {
  const map = useGoogleMap();
  const [selectedTime, setSelectedTime] = useState("");
  const departureAddress = "2440 Main St, Vancouver, BC V5T 3E2"; // Set the departure address
  const [studentAddresses, setStudentAddresses] = useState([]);
  const [studentETAs, setStudentETAs] = useState([]);
  const [isGoogleMapsLoaded, setIsGoogleMapsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const { findAndRenderRoute, directionsRenderer } = useDirectionsService({
    renderOnMap: true,
    renderOptions: {
      suppressMarkers: true,
      polylineOptions: { strokeColor: "#FB2576", strokeWeight: 4 },
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Automatically set the selected time to the present date and time
    const now = new Date();
    const formattedTime = `${now.toISOString().slice(0, 16)}`;
    setSelectedTime(formattedTime);

    // Fetch student addresses based on their IDs
    const fetchStudentAddresses = async () => {
      try {
        const addresses = await Promise.all(
          students.map(async (student) => {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/students/${student}`);
            if (response.ok) {
              const data = await response.json();
              return data.address;
            } else {
              console.error(
                `Failed to fetch student address for ID: ${student.id}`
              );
              return null;
            }
          })
        );

        // Filter out any null addresses (failed requests)
        const validAddresses = addresses.filter((address) => address !== null);
        setStudentAddresses(validAddresses);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching student addresses:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchStudentAddresses();
  }, [students]);

  const calculateRouteAndETA = useCallback(() => {
    if (!studentAddresses || studentAddresses.length === 0 || !selectedTime) {
      return;
    }

    // Form Request to pass to findAndRenderRoute
    const request = {
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      origin: departureAddress,
      destination: studentAddresses[studentAddresses.length - 1],
      waypoints: studentAddresses.slice(0, -1).map((address) => ({
        location: address,
        stopover: true,
      })),
      drivingOptions: {
        departureTime: new Date(selectedTime),
        trafficModel: google.maps.TrafficModel.BEST_GUESS,
      },
    };

    findAndRenderRoute(request)
      .then((result) => {
        // Handle the result
        const route = result.routes[0];
        const leg = route.legs[0];

        const updatedStudentETAs = studentAddresses.map((address, index) => {
          return {
            address,
            eta: leg.duration_in_traffic.value * (index + 1),
          };
        });

        setStudentETAs(updatedStudentETAs);
      })
      .catch((errorStatus) => {
        console.error(errorStatus);
      });
  }, [studentAddresses, selectedTime, departureAddress, findAndRenderRoute]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadGoogleMapsScript = () => {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLEMAPS_APIKEY}&libraries=places`;
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;

      script.onload = () => {
        setIsGoogleMapsLoaded(true);
      };

      document.head.appendChild(script);
    };

    if (!isGoogleMapsLoaded) {
      loadGoogleMapsScript();
    }
  }, [isGoogleMapsLoaded]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isGoogleMapsLoaded) {
      calculateRouteAndETA();
    }
  }, [isGoogleMapsLoaded, calculateRouteAndETA]);

  // Cleanup the directionsRenderer when the component unmounts
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (directionsRenderer) {
        directionsRenderer.setMap(null);
      }
    };
  }, [directionsRenderer]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="datetime-local"
          value={selectedTime}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedTime(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div id="map" style={{ width: "100%", height: "400px" }} />
      <div>
        <h2>Student ETAs:</h2>
        <ul>
          {studentETAs.map((studentETA, index) => (
            <li key={studentAddresses[index]}>
              {studentAddresses[index]}: {studentETA.eta} seconds
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GoogleMapsDirections;
```

Error:

The error I'm encountering is related to the google object not being defined:

'google' is not defined  no-undef

I have set up the GoogleMapsProvider and wrapped my components as instructed in the documentation of @ubilabs/google-maps-react-hooks.
I have also made sure that the Google Maps script is being loaded correctly.
Question:

What might be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Is there something I'm missing in my setup or configuration when using the @ubilabs/google-maps-react-hooks library with React?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you're using React, one solution is to define `google` using `window`, like so:

`const google = window.google;`

According to this answer: [google is not defined in react app using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714895/google-is-not-defined-in-react-app-using-create-react-app)